# Download a file only if a checkbox is checked and form submits

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, jquery

I would like a PDF to download only if a user checks a checkbox and the form submits. Right now the PDF downloads as long as they check the checkbox and hit the submit button. It doesn't matter if the form submits. The main issue is I am limited to Jquery or plain javascript. I do not have access to the backend files. Does anybody know of anyway to do this? The checkbox does not need to be required. Here is the code I have right now:

```
$("#formid").submit(function(ev){
                  ev.preventDefault();
                  $.ajax({
                      url: 'processing.cfc', // background processing procedures
                      type: 'get', 
                      dataType: 'json', 
                      data: $("#formid input, #formid select").serialize(), //pass all present input variables
                      success: formReturn, 
                      failure: function(){ alert("There was an error processing your request. \nPlease try again."); return false; }
                  }); 
                  var $choice = $(this).find("input[name='checkbox1']:checked");//get the selected option 
                    if ($choice.length)// if an option is selected
                    window.open('http://whitepaper.com/info/whitepaper/WhyBuy_WhitePaper_FinalB.pdf') ;

                  var $choice2 = $(this).find("input[name='checkbox2']:checked");//get the selected option 
                    if ($choice2.length)// if an option is selected
                    window.open('http://brochure.com/info/brochure/welcome-kit-brochure.pdf') ;
              });
```

And here is the HTML for the checkboxes:

```
<div class="chkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="regular-checkbox" name="checkbox1" 
  id="checkbox-1-1"><label for="checkbox-1-1"></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span class="dld">Clayton Homes guide to buying a home</span>
</div>
<div class="chkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="regular-checkbox" name="checkbox2" 
  id="checkbox-1-2"><label for="checkbox-1-2"></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <span class="dld">Why Clayton Homes brochure</span>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the PDF opening the success call of the AJAX function.

The key thing here: the AJAX call is *asynchronous*, so the PDF will be opened right after the AJAX request was fired and not after the response arrived.
Something like this:

```
$("#formid").submit(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'processing.cfc', // background processing procedures
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $("#formid input, #formid select").serialize(), //pass all present input variables
        success: function () {
            var $choice = $("#formid input[name='checkbox1']:checked"); //get the selected option 
            if ($choice.length) { // if an option is selected
                window.open('http://whitepaper.com/info/whitepaper/WhyBuy_WhitePaper_FinalB.pdf');
            } else {
                var $choice2 = $("#formid input[name = 'checkbox2']:checked "); //get the selected option 
                if ($choice2.length) { // if an option is selected
                    window.open('http://brochure.com/info/brochure/welcome-kit-brochure.pdf');
                }
            }
        },
        failure: function () {
            alert("
                There was an error processing your request.\nPlease
                try again.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
    },
    failure: function () {
        alert("There was an error processing your request. \nPlease try again.");
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. That works except the formReturn that was the original success parameter needs to be there as well. I should have included the javascript validation with it but it basically processes all of the form fields. Is there anyway to include that in with the PDF files? Thanks again.

Comment: Include what in the PDF files? The html form validation?

Comment: No, include the formReturn parameter in the Success part of the AJAX Post along with the PDF download.

Answer (score 0):

```
`<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG1m" id="checkbox_a" class="css-checkbox" />`
`$`("#checkbox_a").click(function(){
    if($("#checkbox_a").is(':checked')){
      window.open("x.pdf");
    }
});
```